# Not able to fetch historical blocks with Role: Authority

Tags: polkadot, validator, substrate-archive

I am using polkadot v0.9.25 and run it on dev mode, it's **role is authority** and after 256 block when I try to fetch the data of 1 block it shows error `Unable to retrieve the specified block details. -32000: Client error: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for BlockId::Hash(0xe6e95f56950c847fc44b59ad41a5060750a3b10f60fb4fe2c20fb9b1472098f9)`
Is there any way to fetch the data of historical blocks without stopping the chain or is there any other flag which help me to fetch the block data.

Comment: Did you try searching here for your error message? It looks like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use any `--pruning xxx`/`--unsafe-pruning` flag?

Or maybe it is the default behavior in Substrate now.

Try booting with `--pruning archive`. And I think it will make a fully resync.